# jquery load function with a twig template file

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

i'm trying to load a twig file template with the load() function of jquery. 
But i don't know how to write the path for the template .

Is it like this ?

```
htmlObject.load("LeymaxDashboardBundle:AdminPlaine:aucun.html.twig");
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an controller that will return template content. Then use FOSJsRoutingBundle to approach its route from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery.load function expects a valid URL to sent the request to.

So you need to create the URL to a controller and pass it into the jQuery function

```
{{  path('route_name') }}
```

Inside the action of the controller you can proceed in different ways.
Handle the logic you want to achieve and return a Response that matches your needs.

- create a JSON response with partial data

`return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));`

- create a normal response with a twig template reference

`return $this->render('MyProjectMyBundle:ControllerName:template.html.twig');`

Answer (score -1):

i have a idea you can try...In your Controller

```
 public function someAction()
 {
    return $this->render('LeymaxDashboardBundle:AdminPlaine:aucun.html.twig');
 }
```

configure in  routing.yml

Jquery

```
 load("{{path('the route')}}");
```

of course this is just my idea, i don't kown if it will work.you can try...

Comment: thank you but it is not working the value of the jquery var is still empty